# Path conditions from a call to checkBranchCondition

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I would like to get the path constraints for each possible branch in a program.

Say I have a simple program

```
int x;
cin >> x;

if (x > 0) {
    cout << "Path A";
}
else {
    cout << "Path B";
}
```

I would like my checker to be able to determine there are two possible paths in this program.

The condition for path A is `x > 0` and the condition for path B is `x <= 0`.

I can register a callback to run at each split in the paths with checkBranchCondition, but is there a way to get the path conditions?

Comment: Sounds like you want to be writing a [ClangTidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) check or some other tool based on [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html). Unless you want to waste the next 20 years writing a compiler yourself.

Comment: @JesperJuhl actually OP means to use llvm by tags, but I agree it is completely unclear from question itself. OP you should edit your question and make it clearer.